Firebase Function Just Stops with Promises
I have a firebase https function (uses onRequest).  It gets 3800 categories, and batches them into promises.
  async function hideCategories(req, res) {
try {
  const appId = req.query.id

  if (isEmpty(appId) && res) {
    // *- If function is on a schedule it won't have a response
    res.status(404).send('App ID is a required parameter.')
  }

  if (res) {
    res.status(200).send({ status: 'Job Started', code: 200 })
  }

  // *- iterate through each category and check the total count of products that are online and in inventory
  // *- add that category to firebase with hide: true if it is empty
  const categories = await getCategoriesAndLevels(appId, 3)
  // *- Copy the categories since we're splicing categories later
  const clearanceCategories = { ...categories }

  const queryCount = clearanceCategories.length + categories.length
  const categoryIdsToHide = []
  const categoryIdsToShow = []

  let categoryCount = 0

  while (categories.length) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await Promise.all([
      ...categories.splice(0, 5).map((category) => {
        const { id, level } = category
        let productCountPromise = null
        // *- Only check for level 3 and above
        if (level >= 3) {
          productCountPromise = getProductCount(appId, id)
        }
        categoryCount += 1
        return productCountPromise
          ? productCountPromise.then((productCount) => {
              // *- only hide categories for level 3 and below, show categories with products for the same
              if (productCountPromise <= 0) {
                categoryIdsToHide.push(id)
              } else if (productCountPromise > 0) {
                categoryIdsToShow.push(id)
              }
            })
          : productCountPromise
      }),
      () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)),
    ])
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`Error processing categories: ${error}`)
}
}

This function runs 5 HTTP request and waits 1000 ms so that the API can recover.  The API is not timing out, but the firebase function just stops and never goes past this while loop.  Do I have a unresolved promise somehow?  The function will run for about 6 minutes and it stops on varying number of categories.
There's no error, and the timeout is set for 60 min on v2 firebase functions.

Please edit the question to show the full code of the function, including how you declare it and send a response from it.  Sending the response is related to potential timeouts since http functions only terminate after the response is fully sent.  Also it would be nice to see some logging that demonstrates where is the last line of code that is known to execute before things appear to stop.

Also I think it's important for you to show without doubt that getProductCount always returns with the expected value, and that it is not actually the thing blocking your function from completing.  We can't see the code, so we don't know what it does at all, except apparently return a promise..

Updated.  Also yes I have confirmed that getProductCount works as expected.  I have split this up 100 ways.  I have used all async/await, all promises, I have removed all async calls to see if it will finish the promise.all  It consistently stops at 6-8 min making me think it's a timeout, but it's HTTP with timeout at 60 min.

@MattHudson To quote the docs on HTTP Request Functions, "Always end an HTTP function with send(), redirect(), or end()". This has caught out many developers because HTTPS functions end when the request does, but event functions (callables, firestore, etc) stay alive with Promises. If you want to do the "trigger this task via a webhook" workflow, write the information out to Cloud Firestore or the Task Scheduler (somewhere you can attach a functions trigger) and perform the task in that function.

Here is a Scheduler example, PubSub example 1, and PubSub example 2. Annoyingly I can't find the previous answer where I described how to use HTTPS request functions to start long-running tasks by writing the request data out to Firestore, using an onCreate trigger to do the actual work and connecting the client so that it listens for document updates for progress reports.

Rather than trying to fix your code, I will suggest a different approach:
// Define a couple of helper functions: take and filter
function* take(n, iter) {
    let { value, done } = iter.next();
    while (n > 0 && n-- && !done) {
        yield value;
        ({ value, done } = iter.next());
    }
}
function* filter(pred, iter) {
    let { value, done } = iter.next();
    while (!done) {
        if (pred(value))
            yield value;
        ({ value, done } = iter.next());
    }
}
// iterator is stateful, no need to splice array
// we can also lazily yield up only the categories
// that pass the level check.
const categoriesIterable = filter(
  ({ level }) => level >= 3, 
  categories[Symbol.iterator](),
);

const categoriesIter = categoriesIterable[Symbol.iterator]();
let batch = [...take(5, categoriesIter)];
const idsToHide = [];
const idsToShow = [];
while (batch.length) {
    // NOTE: top-level await only works in ES module files.
    // if you need this to work in commonJS wrap in an
    // async function or IIFE
    await Promise.all(batch.map(async ({ id }) => {
        const count = await getProductCount(appId, id);
        if (count) {
            idsToShow.push(id);
        }
        else {
            idsToHide.push(id);
        }
    }));

    // wait 1 sec
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 1000));

    // queue up the next batch
    batch = [...take(5, categoriesIter)];
}

This uses generators and iterators to consume the categories from the array 5 at a time and process them. Note that other than the helper functions the code is extremely straightforward. The helpers themselves are basically just lodash functions but implemented to work for iterators rather than just arrays.
The reason I'm suggesting that you abandon your current approach is that it is basically untestable. How would you write unit tests to verify each behavior in that processing logic? It's hard to test, hard to debug, and tries to cram too many different concerns together: batching, filtering, iteration, async data fetches, rate-limiting, not to mention the business logic!
Here's a typed version in Typescript if anyone needs the types.

As a side note, if anyone likes this style I did write a library to make it a little easier.

Well that is all true, and verified by large bruises on my forehead.
